# objective-c : Use a array to point to another array

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsindexpath

I have two Mutable arrays. 
"friendsArray" contains a whole list os users and "inviteIndex" contains the indexes (indexPath.row) of some of them (get using uiswitch button into a table list).

The I fill inviteIndex array as:

```
[inviteIndex addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]];
```

In order to have only  selected  users I do:

```
  for (int i =0; i< [inviteIndex count]; i++) {

        MyElement  *friend =[friendsArray objectAtIndex:[inviteIndex objectAtIndex:i] ];

        NSLog(@"BUTTON PRESSED %@", friend.friendId);

    }
```

but app crash with message:

```
[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 400931632 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]'
```

I trid used
  `MyElement  *friend =[friendsArray objectAtIndex:(NSInteger)[inviteIndex objectAtIndex:i] ];`
 with same result.

Any help please?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[inviteIndex objectAtIndex:i]` will return an `NSNumber` object.  You want the `NSInteger` value *within* the `NSNumber` object:

```
for (int i =0; i< [inviteIndex count]; i++) {

    NSInteger index = [[inviteIndex objectAtIndex:i] integerValue];
    MyElement  *friend =[friendsArray objectAtIndex:index];

    NSLog(@"BUTTON PRESSED %@", friend.friendId);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **index beyond bounds** this error comes when you're trying to access an object 
>       from an index which are not exist in array.

In your case, seems that `friendArray`s count is < (less than the) `inviteIndex` count.

I think the problem is somewhere in this logic, `[inviteIndex addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]];`

Check count of `inviteIndex`.